# XSL Transformation: select XPath property value based on current nodes property value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Turning xml into html, I would like to assign a classname to an element based on information that is stored somewhere else in the xml-document. To do this, I need to insert the value of a property of the current node into an XPath. I do not know how to do this.

Given this xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
     <Styles>
      <Style ss:ID="cell-ID" ss:Name="classname">
      </Style>
     </Styles>
     <Worksheet>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="cell-ID">test</Cell>
       </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
```

I have used the following XSL, but the line with the arrow pointer does not work:

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                    xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" 
                    exclude-result-prefixes="ss"
                    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="style">
            <xsl:for-each select="Workbook/Styles/Style">
                #<xsl:value-of select="@ss:ID"/>
                    <xsl:if  test="@ss:Name">, .<xsl:value-of select="@ss:Name" /></xsl:if> { ... }
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:for-each select="Workbook/Worksheet/Cell">
            <xsl:element name="div">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">default</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="@ss:StyleID">
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@ss:StyleID"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">
==>                     <xsl:value-of select="//Style[@ss:ID=@ss:StyleID]/@ss:Name"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The desired output would be

```html
<style>
   #cell-ID, .classname { ... }
</style>
<div class="classname" id="cell-ID">test</div>
```

but the classname remains empty.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT has a built-in [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references.

Consider this minimal example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
exclude-result-prefixes="ss">

<xsl:key name="styl" match="Style" use="@ss:ID" />

<xsl:template match="/Workbook">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="Worksheet/Cell">
                <div class="{key('styl', @ss:StyleID)/@ss:Name}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the input in your question, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="classname">test</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

---

Note the use of (1) [literal result elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#literal-result-element) and (2) [attribute value template](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#attribute-value-templates).

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't quite understand why I should use key before, but now this is much clearer and you helped me solve this problem.